# path-to-regexp not matching when passing arguments as variables

Tags: javascript, regex, routes, path-to-regexp

I've run into a odd problem. When I try to test if `path-to-regexp` will match a given path I will not get a result when expected, if I pass the input string from a variable. But if I hard-code the string directly (i.e. the very same string that is being printed to the console when printing the variable) it works?

Any idea what might be going on here?

I build a little prototype you can [try out](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-cloud-klou4b?file=/src/index.js:0-865)

And here is the code example:

```
import { match } from "path-to-regexp";
const esc = require("./escapeRegexInPath");

const pattern = new RegExp("[0-9]*");

// Does the pattern match "123"
console.log({ patternTest: pattern.test("123") });
// => {patternTest: true}

// The escape function will escape special characters
const escapedRegex = esc(pattern);
console.log({ escapedRegex });
// => {escapedRegex: "[0-9]\*"}

// This matcher is passed the escaped regex as a variable
const matcher = match(`:entityId(${escapedRegex})`);

// And it fails to match anything with input "123"
console.log({ matcher: matcher("123") });
// {matcher: false}

// This matcher is passed a hardcoded regex
// And it succesfully matches with input "123"
const matcher2 = match(`:entityId([0-9]\*)`);
console.log({ matcher2: matcher2("123") });
// => {matcher2: Object}
```

Comment: Because you're escaping half the characters out in the first example...?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. I'm escaping the asterisk. But the key point is that I'm using the same regex in matcher and matcher2, so I'm escaping it in both places. Or are you seeing something I'm not seeing?

Comment: On the point of escaping. I can't find explicit mention of the need to escape on the path-to-regexp readme, but I'm using the Next.js and only interacting with path-to-regexp directly in order to write tests for my routes. In the Next.js docs it is stated that you need to escape a number of characters used by the special path syntax. Perhaps Next.js adds another layer on top of `path-to-regexp`? https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#regex-path-matching